# CNTK Input Data Structure for example: CSTrainingCPUOnlyExamples

Tags: c#, cntk

I am using the Example of CNTK: [LSTMSequenceClassifier](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Examples/TrainingCSharp/Common/LSTMSequenceClassifier.cs) via the Console Application: [CSTrainingCPUOnlyExamples](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Examples/TrainingCSharp/CSTrainingCPUOnlyExamples/Program.cs), using the default data file: [Train.ctf](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tests/EndToEndTests/Text/SequenceClassification/Data/Train.ctf), it looks like this:

[image]

The Input Layer is dimension: 2000 ( **One Hot Vector** ), the Output is: 5 Classes ( **Softmax** ).

The File is loaded via:

```
MinibatchSource minibatchSource = MinibatchSource.TextFormatMinibatchSource(Path.Combine(DataFolder, "Train.ctf"), streamConfigurations, MinibatchSource.InfinitelyRepeat, true);

StreamInformation featureStreamInfo = minibatchSource.StreamInfo(featuresName);

StreamInformation labelStreamInfo = minibatchSource.StreamInfo(labelsName);
```

I would really appreciate how the data file is generated and how 2000 Inputs map to 5 classes Output.

Of course, my goal is to write an application to Format and save Data to a file that can be read as an Input Data File. Of course I would need to understand the Structure to make this work.

Thanks!

I see the Y Dimension, this part makes sense, but am having trouble with the Input Layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** @Frank Seide MSFT

I wonder if you can verify and give best practices:

```
private string Format(int sequenceId, string featureName, string featureShape, string labelName, string featureComment, string labelShape, string labelComment)
{
    return $"{sequenceId} |{featureName.Replace(" ","-")} {featureShape} |# {featureComment}   |{labelName.Replace(" ","-")} {labelShape} |# {labelComment}\r\n";
}
```

which might return something like:

```
0 |x 560:1 |# I am a comment   |y 1 0 0 0 0 |# I am a comment
```

Where:

- sequenceId = 0;
- featureName = "x";
- featureShape = "560:1";
- featureComment = "I am a comment";
- labelName = "y";
- labelShape = "1 0 0 0 0";
- labelComment = "I am a comment";

On GPU, Frank did suggest around 20 Sequences for each Minibatch, see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TK671HxrufE @26:25

This is for custom C# Dataset formatting.

**End edit...**

An accidental discovery and I found an answer with some Documentation:

> [BrainScript CNTK Text Format Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/brainscript-cntktextformat-reader) using CNTKTextFormatReader

The documtnet goes on to explain:

> CNTKTextFormatReader (later simply CTF Reader) is designed to consume input text data formatted according to the specification below. It supports the following main features:
>   Multiple input streams (inputs) per file
>   Both sparse and dense inputs
>   Variable length sequences
>   CNTK Text Format (CTF)
>   Each line in the input file contains one sample for one or more inputs. Since (explicitly or implicitly) every line is also attached to a sequence, it defines one or more sequence, input, sample relations. Each input line must be formatted as follows:
>   [Sequence_Id](Sample or Comment)+
>   .
>   where
>   Sample=|Input_Name (Value )*
>   Comment=|# some content
>   Each line starts with a sequence id and contains one or more samples (in other words, each line is an unordered collection of samples).
>   Sequence id is a number. It can be omitted, in which case the line number will be used as the sequence id.
>   Each sample is effectively a key-value pair consisting of an input name and the corresponding value vector (mapping to higher dimensions is done as part of the network itself).
>   Each sample begins with a pipe symbol (|) followed by the input name (no spaces), followed by a whitespace delimiter and then a list of values.
>   Each value is either a number or an index-prefixed number for sparse inputs.
>   Both tabs and spaces can be used interchangeably as delimiters.
>   A comment starts with a pipe immediately followed by a hash symbol: |#, then followed by the actually content (body) of the comment. The body can contain any characters, however a pipe symbol inside the body needs to be escaped by appending the hash symbol to it (see the example below). The body of a comment continues until the end of line or the next un-escaped pipe, whichever comes first.

Handy, and gives an answer.

> The input data corresponding to the reader configuration above should look something like this: 
>   |B 100:3 123:4 |C 8 |A 0 1 2 3 4 |# a CTF comment
>   |# another comment |A 0 1.1 22 0.3 54 |C 123917 |B 1134:1.911 13331:0.014
>   |C -0.001 |# a comment with an escaped pipe: '|#' |A 3.9 1.11 121.2 99.13 0.04 |B 999:0.001 918918:-9.19
>
> Note the following about the input format:
>   |Input_Name identifies the beginning of each input sample. This element is mandatory and is followed by the correspondent value vector.
>   Dense vector is just a list of floating point values; sparse vector is a list of index:value tuples.
>   Both tabs and spaces are allowed as value delimiters (within input vectors) as well as input delimiters (between inputs).
>   Each separate line constitutes a "sequence" of length 1 ("Real" variable-length sequences are explained in the extended example below).
>   Each input identifier can only appear once on a single line (which translates into one sample per input per line requirement).
>   The order of input samples within a line is NOT important (conceptually, each line is an unordered collection of key-value pairs)
>   Each well-formed line must end with either a "Line Feed" \n or "Carriage Return, Line Feed" \r\n symbols.

Some awesome content on the Input and Label Data in this Video:

https://youtu.be/hMRrqkl77rI - @30:23
https://youtu.be/Vi05nEzAS8Y - @25:20

Also, helpful but not directly related: [Read and feed data to CNTK Trainer](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/Manual_How_to_feed_data.html)